# Traceback error when attempting to add a reference or background image in 2.8

Tags: python, image, error

I'm at [Level 3 - Part 1 of BlenderGuru's Beginner Tutorial for 2.8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7a0cHFs7jkw&t=4s) and I'm receiving the following error when I attempt to add a reference image:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\scripts\startup\bl_operators\object.py", line 918, in execute obj.data = image
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

I've tried uninstalling & reinstalling Blender a couple of times and even updated and restarted my Macbook - nothing has worked.

I am able to add reference images to new files, but not the tutorial file I've been working on. I can't add background images to it either. 
Please help me fix this.

Comment: i struggled with same problem you have to turn on the overlay mine fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had this same problem.
I was trying to add the image to a hidden collection.
Adding to an unhidden collection gave me the reference.

Comment: That may have been my issue as well. Thank you for sharing! I'll keep it in mind during my next Blender experience :)

Answer (score 0):

I am just going to assume this error is just a bug or something.

I worked around it by creating a new file, uploaded my reference image and sculpted the object there, and then appended it to my donut file.

I hope this helps anyone struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just moved the reference file to C:\, and this solved the problem